# R: How to use $ when the name is stored in a variable?

Tags: r, string, list

Here is an example using a `list` of the issue I am facing.

```
mylist = list("hello" = c(2,3))
name = "hello"
```

How can I access the element called `hello` in `mylist` using only the variable `name`? I tried

```
mylist$name
mylist$get("name")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `mylist[[name]]`.

Comment: Oh well... that was easy. You can make an answer out of your comment. Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b why you accepted a solution which is the copy of above comment? Pascal is the one who provides the solution at very first.

Comment: I accepted an answer that was slightly more complete. But assuming that it actually sounds more fair to reward the one who answered first, I changed my check to Pascal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to use `[[`

```
mylist[[name]]
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: plus 1 for your comment. Why you provide answer in comments?

Comment: It is a basic feature of R.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
mylist$hello
```

or

```
 mylist[[name]]
```